# Unable to Deploy Liferay hooks in Liferay 6.2 Community Edition

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I have been trying to migrate the code from Liferay 6.2 Enterprise edition to Community edition based on company requirement. I successfully migrated portlets, EXT, and theme but while I try to deploy hooks and restart the server, I get the following error once the server is fully restarted:

> 12:59:14,843 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-1][IncludeTag:129] Current URL / generates exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.html.taglib.aui.input.page_jsp
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.html.taglib.aui.input.page_jsp
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:121)

I receive the above error once the server is restarted and my login screen appears without textbox. Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

That's pointing to a missing  tag, but those should both be available in CE and EE.

You purged your work and temp folders, right?